# css Unwanted Margin in Parent div

Tags: html, css, margin

I am frustrated trying to fix this issue, but couldn't tackle it.

I have a simple html page structure:

**header div, body div, and a footer div.**

The problem is that the content of the body `div` (`.form-container`) affects the `margin` of the body `div` itself (`.body-container`).

**Example:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.header-container {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.body-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  background: #fff url('http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/paper.gif') repeat scroll left top;
}
.footer-container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.form-container {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container"></div>
<div class="body-container">
  <div class="form-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer-container"></div>
```

How do I get rid of this `margin` in the body `div`?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## This is due to margin collapsing

This is expected behaviour, Mozilla Developer Network states:

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

*[Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)*

In this case the conditions are met by `.body-container` and `.form-container` so the `margin` of `.form-container` ends up outside `.body-container`.

## What can you do?

There are a number of ways you can stop this behaviour although the easiest would be to use `padding` instead of `margin` on `.form-container` as `padding` does not collapse.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.header-container {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.body-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  background: #fff url('http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/paper.gif') repeat scroll left top;
}
.footer-container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.form-container {
  padding: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container"></div>
<div class="body-container">
  <div class="form-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this part to remove the unwanted margin :

```
        .form-container{
            margin-bottom:30px;
            margin-top:30px;
        }
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omx1rnxf/1/)

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the space, you can use a `padding-top` instead.

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/omx1rnxf/4/)

```
.form-container{
  padding-top : 30px;
}
```

**Note**

This property `background-color: green;` of `.body-container` is not applied because of the `background` property below which has a white background-color property set here : `background: #fff url('http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/paper.gif') repeat scroll left top;`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, I want the margin, I want the div inside the body div to have a space from the it's parent div "the body div", but the problem is that, this margin also affects the parent div background image, it acts as a padding for the body div, why!

Answer (score 1):

There is a div `.form-container` in body div in which follwing css is applied

```
.form-container{
        margin-bottom:30px;
        margin-top:30px;
    }
```

Because there is no content in this div its showing top and bottom margin so u can use `float:left` or `dislay:inline` property of you cant remove the css or if you can then simply remove this css.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   
   body{
    margin:0px;
   }
   
   .header-container{
    height:250px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: red;
   }
   
   .body-container{
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: green;
    background: #fff url('http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/paper.gif') repeat scroll left top;
   }
   
   .footer-container{
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: blue;
   }
   
   .form-container{
    margin-bottom:30px;
    margin-top:30px;
    float:left;
   }
   
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="header-container"></div>
  <div class="body-container">
  
   <div class="form-container">
   </div>
   
  </div>
  <div class="footer-container"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
Add "margin-top:-30px" to the .body-container part
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   
   body{
    margin:0px;
   }
   
   .header-container{
    height:250px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: red;
   }
   
   .body-container{
              margin-top:-30px;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: green;
    background: #fff url('http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/paper.gif') repeat scroll left top;
   }
   
   .footer-container{
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: blue;
   }
   
   .form-container{
    margin-bottom:30px;
    margin-top:30px;
   }
   
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="header-container"></div>
  <div class="body-container">
  
   <div class="form-container">
   </div>
   
  </div>
  <div class="footer-container"></div>
 </body>
</html>
► Run code snippetCopy snippet to answer
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make the header, body and footer div float, the extra space disappears.

The float makes them try to stick together, but your width: 100% makes sure they each are page wide.

I've also edited your code a bit.

```html
                    <html>
                <head>
                  <style>

                  body{
                    margin:0px;
                }

                .header-container{
                    height:250px;
                    width:100%;
                    background-color: red;
                    float: left;
                }

                .body-container{
                    height:500px;
                    width:100%;
                    background: url('http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/paper.gif') repeat scroll left;
                    float: left;
                }

                .footer-container{
                    height:150px;
                    width:100%;
                    background-color: blue;
                    float: left;
                }

                .form-container{
                    margin-bottom:30px;
                    margin-top:30px;
                }

                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
              <div class="header-container"></div>
              <div class="body-container">

                 <div class="form-container">
                 </div>

             </div>
             <div class="footer-container"></div>
            </body>
            </html>
```